# org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject Resttemplate

Tags: android, json, resttemplate

I got a little problem with getting my JSON Object.

```
            try {
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject( response.getBody());
                JSONObject userObject = jObject.getJSONObject("data");
                String nachricht = userObject.getString("nachricht");
                String ausgeloest_von = userObject.getString("ausgeloest_von");
                String erstellt_am = userObject.getString("erstellt_am");
```

I get the error at data of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject at the second line in my code snippet. I have the same code on a different API and its working.

{
    "error": 200,
    "message": "Daten gefunden",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "105",
            "userid": "9981",
            "userid_notfall": "9985",
            "nachricht": "Notfall von Max",
            "ausgeloest_von": "",
            "status": "0",
            "erstellt_am": "2017-11-28 18:10:48",
            "aktualisiert_am": ""
        }
    ]
}

This is what the response body looks like. I think the "[" brackets causing my problems. Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
 JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject( response.getBody());      JSONArray userArray= jObject.getJSONArray("data"); 
 for(int i =0;i < userArray.length();i++) {
      JSONObject individualObject = userArray.getJSONObject(i);
      String nachricht = userObject.getString("nachricht"); 
      String ausgeloest_von = userObject.getString("ausgeloest_von");           String erstellt_am = userObject.getString("erstellt_am");
 }
```

Comment: No worry Michael. Just one thing please upvote my answer too

Comment: I am unable to because I have less than 15 points in reputation :)